# Error when init database postgresql 10.10: PANIC: could not generate secret authorization token

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a problem when run command: `sudo -su user_test ./pgsql/bin/initdb -D /example/folder` 
I had researched many sources from the internet but don’t found a solution.
I hope everyone could help me. Thanks.

Enviroment:

- initdb (PostgreSQL) 10.10
- OS: uname -a Linux DL2100 3.10.38 #1 SMP Build-gitb1820a8 x86_64 GNU/Linux

````
selecting default max_connections … 100
selecting default shared_buffers … 128MB
selecting default timezone … Europe/Helsinki
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation … posix
creating configuration files … ok
running bootstrap script … 2020-11-03 11:52:56.303 EET [3928] DEBUG: invoking IpcMemoryCreate(size=148545536)
2020-11-03 11:52:56.303 EET [3928] DEBUG: mmap(148897792) with MAP_HUGETLB failed, huge pages disabled: Cannot allocate memory
2020-11-03 11:52:56.315 EET [3928] DEBUG: SlruScanDirectory invoking callback on pg_notify/0000
2020-11-03 11:52:56.315 EET [3928] DEBUG: removing file "pg_notify/0000"
2020-11-03 11:52:56.316 EET [3928] DEBUG: dynamic shared memory system will support 288 segments
2020-11-03 11:52:56.316 EET [3928] DEBUG: created dynamic shared memory control segment 1852866650 (6928 bytes)
2020-11-03 11:52:56.319 EET [3928] PANIC: could not generate secret authorization token
Aborted
child process exited with exit code 134```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown in `BootStrapXLOG` in `src/backend/access/transam/xlog.c`:

```c
    /*
     * Generate a random nonce. This is used for authentication requests that
     * will fail because the user does not exist. The nonce is used to create
     * a genuine-looking password challenge for the non-existent user, in lieu
     * of an actual stored password.
     */
    if (!pg_backend_random(mock_auth_nonce, MOCK_AUTH_NONCE_LEN))
        ereport(PANIC,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_INTERNAL_ERROR),
                 errmsg("could not generate secret authorization token")));
```

`src/backend/utils/misc/backend_random.c` says:

```
pg_backend_random() function fills a buffer with random bytes. Normally,
it is just a thin wrapper around pg_strong_random(), but when compiled
with --disable-strong-random, we provide a built-in implementation.
```

So it seems that PostgreSQL was built on a system that had a source for strong random numbers (OpenSSL or `/dev/urandom`, if you are not on Windows), but the facility is not working on your current system.

- try with the lates minor release of v10 (currently 10.15) – maybe a bug has been fixed.
- run `pg_config --configure` to check if PostgreSQL was built `--with-openssl`
- OpenSSL also uses `/dev/urandom`, so there is likely a problem with that source of random numbers; investigate there

If all fails, build PostgreSQL from source and configure it with

```sh
./configure --disable-strong-random ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine. Thank you very much, @Laurenz Albe